# Routing network communication

Tags: networking, server, iptables

Hi I try to do following (Ips are examples):

- I have source computer with IP 50.50.50.1
- I have destination computer
  with IP 50.50.40.1 (It is not accessible from source computer)
- I have gateway's computer with IP 50.50.30.1 (It is accessible from source
  computer and there is connection to destination computer via network
  adapter tun0

Communication should be looks like this:

`50.50.50.1 (default adapter) -> 50.50.40.1 (tun0 adapter) -> 50.50.30.1`

Is it possible to configure something like this in routing table in gateway's computer?

I use ubuntu 16.04

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I can use the NAT tables:

```
# the ip of node which is in MSD network. This can be for example edge node
IP_OF_SOURCE_NODE=50.50.50.1
# ip of destination database where we want to connect (do not forget on port)
IP_OF_DESTINATION_NODE=50.50.30.1:22
# ip address of VPN network adapter
IP_OF_VPN_NETWORK_ADAPTER=50.50.51.1

# Need to change the destination ip to database ip for the packets incoming from default network from specific source (for example dge node) 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens5 -p tcp -s ${IP_OF_SOURCE_NODE} --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination ${IP_OF_DESTINATION_DATABASE}

# Need to change the source ip to inet address of vpn network address for packets leaving VPN network adapter
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -p tcp -s ${IP_OF_SOURCE_NODE} --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source ${IP_OF_VPN_NETWORK_ADAPTER}
```

After this I successfully connect to node 50.50.30.1 from 50.50.50.1 via 50.50.40.1